# PHP: will there be any possible harm if I put exit; at the end of the script?

Tags: php, multithreading, codeigniter, exit

Apparently, requests to my CodeIgniter application can save up to **300ms** if I put `exit;` at the end of `index.php`.

```
/*
 * --------------------------------------------------------------------
 * LOAD THE BOOTSTRAP FILE
 * --------------------------------------------------------------------
 *
 * And away we go...
 */
require_once BASEPATH.'core/CodeIgniter.php';

/* End of file index.php */
/* Location: ./index.php */

exit; // <~~ save me ~300ms request time, from ~900ms to ~600ms
```

I know, it's weird, I can't think of any reasonable explanation for this. I'm on my way finding the answer and try to reproduce the behavior in an isolated environment. But in the meantime, in case there is any obvious reason that I am unaware of, I want to ask...

**Will there be any possible harm if I put exit; at the end of the index.php in CodeIgniter 3.0?**

Comment: If it saves time, that likely means code is executing after your main file finishes. It depends on what that extra code does.

Comment: Do you have any suggestion on how could I find what are the "extra code"?

Comment: AFAIK, php code is synchronous, and this index.php is the first script every request go to, so the "extra code" must be something like multi threads or child processes that are created by the main script? Is that right? I don't remember using any of those in my scripts. Is there any common php built-in methods that cause this? Can I use XDebug to see the "extra code"?

Comment: have you considered turning off the xdebug extension and test it again ?
if i do that on a windows machine - all php scripts works smoother and faster - i'm asking this because your exit is the end of the file anyway.
Write in one of your views ´<h3>Rendertime:<?php echo $this->benchmark->elapsed_time();?></h3>´ and look @the execution time with and without your exit and post your results here

Comment: @sintakonte You was right, it was Xdebug. So that's why I wasn't able to see the reason using Xdebug, haha.

Comment: @sintakonte you can add an answer and I'll mark it as accepted.

Comment: thx men i did it now ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered turning off the xdebug extension and test it again ? 
If i do that on a windows machine - all php scripts works smoother and faster -

I'm asking this because your exit is the end of the file anyway. 
Write in one of your views something like

`<h3>Rendertime:<?php echo $this->benchmark->elapsed_time();?></h3>`

And look @the execution time with and without your exit.
Most of the time they would be the same.